# Firebase auth and billing subscriptions

Tags: firebase, subscription, delete-row

I'm new at android studio. If this question has been answered before, I'm sorry to ask again.
I'm trying to build a fitness app and I'm creating workout and nutrition plans for premium users. I need to store user's info so I'm using firebase but it's gonna be monthly subscriptions and after a month I need to delete their infos. I couldn't find a way to delete their auths and infos automatically. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

If you new to firebase, I suggest look at their documentation. They include plenty of tutorials for beginners including setting up your enviroment.

Assuming you are using firebase auth, the FirebaseUser class has methods for removing users from the system.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser

However I assume you will want to use firestore to persist customer information, name address etc (a database and NOT an authentication system).

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#java

With a montly subscription system you will need SERVER logic to enforce such logic. You cannot sensibly do all this just in the client.

Firebase is not a payment processor, for that you would need to intergrate something like stripe.

I've tried to be helpful here, however I must admit this is not a good question by community standards.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Stackoverflow is full of coders trying to help other coders solve specific programming problems. It is not here as a discussion site for how to begin projects of substantial scale.

I wish you good luck, but please recognise your mission is not trivial for a beginner.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question :)